# Struvite crystals

Tags: cats, health, diet, multi-pet-families

I have a five year old cat who was diagnosed with struvite crystals. He's had it ever since he was about one to one and a half year old. He has had a catheter installed a few times and he's now on special food to help. He hasn't had them since 2014, which I'm grateful for!

Is there anything I can do extra or buy to make sure they stay away? I constantly worry about him, because if it happens again I'm afraid I won't be able to pay for the cost of his vet bill this time around if it happens suddenly, which it use to do.

Also, are there any types of treats you can feed cats that have this issue? I always want to treat him and give him something other than his cat food that he's stuck with, but I'm too scared to try regular treats in case they cause the crystals.

Any advice would be helpful and appreciated.

Answer (score 6):

To prevent crystals stay on the veterinary diet your vet recommended. I've had people complain that it's expensive and go back to superstore cat food only to return with another blockage. These diets should be treated as a medication.

Water intake is important, this makes the cat pee more allowing the kidneys and bladder to be flushed more frequently. Adding can food along with his dry is an option or just feed canned food all together (the food your vet recommended will have a wet version of it).

Water fountains can help too although some cats don't like them. Cats typically prefer running water over still.

For treats [royal canin](http://royalcanin.ca/products/catalog/Royal-Canin-Veterinary-Diet-Feline-URINARY-TREATS-for-cats/226054?gclid=CKPVr7H8o9MCFQUIaQodwU8I_A) has some that you can purchase at your vet hospital. 
Some people will also use their prescribed diet as treats as well.